# R - Interpolate between lines that are not vertical or horizontal oriented

Tags: r, interpolation, raster

I am looking for a way to interpolate between lines in a raster. I have a raster file with x and y in GK coordinates and a value for each point on the line:
[Plot with lines to interpolate between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ9iI.png) (I am not yet allowed to add pictures)

Is there a function or a way that allows to only interpolate between the lines? Using `interpolate` from the `Field` package does an interpolation everywhere in the raster space, which is not useful for me.

The aim is to have a filled contour between the lines. So something like this: [Filled contour between two vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0SqN.png). I am able to do that for a vertical or horizontal combination of lines. But not for any other angles.

Comment: Hi Kj. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I ask what precisely you mean by "interpolate between lines"? Do you mean construct an "average" line from all 3 lines, or an "average" of each pair of three lines (giving 3 new lines), or a new line through each equivalent point on each line (or each pair of lines). Perhaps a sketch would help. Also, some reproducible data to test and verify solutions would be much more likely to get you the help you are looking for. Thanks

Comment: Ah yeah sorry. Was not very clear I guess. The aim is to fill the area between the lines with values (wind is blowing perpendicular to the lines) and end up with a filled contour.

Comment: In that case you might want to check out `interp` from the `akima` package, which will carry out 2d interpolation of a set of points. By default this is constrained to the convex hull of your points, but it sounds like this is what you want. It can be tricky to use, but without a reproducible example, I'm not sure how we can be any more specific here.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly! Tank you!